# Laravel: Get root class in nested relationship query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I get the root class in a nested eager relationship? Basically, I want to get something like this:

```php
        $entities = Entity::with(['attribute.valueable' => function ($query) {
            $root = $query->getRootParent();
            $query->where('entity_id', $root->id);
        }])->get();
```

SQL-queries should be like

```
select * from `entities`;

select * from `entity_types_attributes` where `entity_types_attributes`.`entity_type_id` in (?);

select * from `entity_attribute_value_int` where `entity_attribute_value_int`.`attribute_id` in (?, ?, ?) 
AND `entity_attribute_value_int`.entity_id` = ? // this part should be appended
```

Comment: What are the relationships between the models?

Comment: `entity->attribute - belongsTo`
`attribute->valuable - morphOne`